# How to disable Mobile detection (JavaScript) at users request?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mobile

I have a php "header" file with Javascript included that is mobile detection. It will redirect the user to the mobile site if need be. The problem i foresee is that they will never be able to view the full site as long as that mobile-detection script is running.

So how do i go about disabling that script at the users request (i.e View Full Site link)?

This is the basic idea of the "header" php file.

```
<html><title>blah blah</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="large.test.css" />
<script src="slider.js"></script>
<?php include('mobile-detect.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

Here is the JavaScript "mobile-detect.php"

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
(function() {
    var platform = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    var fullExp = /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i;
    var partialExp = /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i;    

    var isMobile = fullExp.test(platform) || partialExp.test(platform.substring(0,4));

    if (isMobile) {
       window.location = <?php echo $mobile; ?>;
    } else {
    }

})(window);

</script>
```

Comment: Via the detection of a cookie, you then exclude your redirection code from being rendered in the output of your page.

Comment: I'm looking into cookies right now. I haven't had the need for them yet, but seemingly the time has come. Should i use PHP $_COOKIE? or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is done by storing a setting on the user's browser via either a cookie or LocalStorage.

If the user opts out of mobile, you set a cookie or LocalStorage value.  Your redirection script then checks that value to see if the user opted out before doing a mobile redirect.

You could use a cookie for the setting if you also want your server to be able to see this setting (all cookies for a given site are sent to the server with each page request) or if the server doesn't need to see the setting (all action on the setting is client-side), then you can use LocalStorage which is a bit easier to program than a cookie.

See this answer from earlier today for more info and references on using LocalStorage: [Using Global Variables between multiple functions in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110290/using-global-variables-between-multiple-functions-in-jquery/25110335#25110335)